# List is printing index value twice

Tags: python, list

I have to print out the 2nd element of the list along with the count. But my output is showing twice the number of elements of the actual data. What to do?

Required output(count)->27
My output(count)->54

Sample data:
http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/mbox-short.txt

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")

fh = open(fname)

count = 0
lst=list()
for line in fh:
    if line.startswith('From'):
        data=line.split()
        print data[1]
        count=count+1
print "There were", count, "lines in the file with From as the first word"
```

Comment: At first blush it seems to be correct. [edit] your question to include a sample file, as well as the output when you run the program on that sample file

Comment: Since lst is assigned but not used in your piece of code, I assume that your code snippet has somehow been cut out of the actual code.  And, as mhlester has mentioned, this piece of code looks ok, the problem my lie in the part of the code you have excluded from the sample.

Comment: This is the complete code. I have tried running it on the sample data, the output is still doubled.

Comment: Umm... Your sample input data actually has 54 lines beginning with `From`, so you're getting the correct results... 27 would be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to match `From`, result is 54. Try to match `From:` and use `with open` construction:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")

with open(fname, 'rb') as fn:

    count = 0
    lst = []
    for line in fn:
        if line.startswith('From:'):
            print line.split()[1]
            count += 1

print "There were", count, "lines in the file with From as the first word"
```

There is a shorter version of what your're doing:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")

with open(fname, 'rb') as fn:
    l = [line.split()[1]for line in fn if line.startswith('From:')]

print "\n".join(l)
print "There were", len(l), "lines in the file with From as the first word"
```

Comment: it works perfectly fine without it, it was just my suggestion to improve OP's code

Comment: The output is still 54 :/

Comment: share your file, i think problem is in your file, i tried on a test file and it works correctly

Comment: Answers are supposed to be solutions to the problem posted. If you want to suggest other improvements that's fine. But if you're not solving the problem, just post it as a comment.

Comment: copy my answer and run it

Comment: Thanks. Sorry folks, I was missing on the colon.

Comment: If the answer helped you , you can accept it by clicking v